# Why do some people lie?

Tags: psychology, social-ethics

Some people lie about such insignificant stuff, like what they had for lunch, or say that they were sleeping when they were actually watching TV. Why do they do this? Has this ever been studied, and if so, what are the chances they can change? Especially if they are over 50 years old?

Comment: That's a very open question.  I find myself wanting to ask you if wearing lipstick is a lie.  A woman's lips are not that color.  Why does she curl her hair with an iron?  Why does a banker wear a power suit?  In these cases, people represent what their peers want to see to gain power.  If someone is lying about trivial things they probably are saying whatever they feel will end the conversation.  In other words, they are indifferent which is the opposite of love.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off topic because it is about psychology, not philosophy

Comment: Your husband is probably lying about sleeping when he was watching TV because he wants a quiet, peaceful life and doesn't get it when he says the truth.

Comment: It is not my husband. It is family. And people I have come across in my life. It is one of those things in life I always wondered about. Why not just tell the truth. The circumstances are so that it doesn't matter one way or another. Compulsive liars? Maybe. I feel it hurts them more than anyone else because if you lie about something so trivial, what about the stuff that isn't trivial? Once a liar, always a liar? Just something I always wondered about. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Every habit we have is learnt. During our early developmental years we learn by copying adult behaviour. This is before we learn what is right and wrong. These behaviour patterns reside in our subconscious memory and most people do not even know why they do what they do. The right brain tries to rationalize the behaviour but generally when they say they don't know why they do things they are speaking the truth. To someone who has learnt a different behaviour pattern this would not make sense as their left and right brain patterns correspond.

Comment: That is a good answer. Maybe it is a defense mechanism people use when they feel guilty about something totally different. It just really intrigues me.